# How to perform tasks avoiding the user being forced to wait the response?

Tags: php, symfony, task

After user created a new product, in my application then I do several operation like update few tables: stats, financial, usage, stock, etc.

Now users must wait for I've finished all steps. If a lot of user tray do it at the same time then time to wait is much more and that's not so good.

My plan is to create a special TASK_TABLE (product_id, time, task_id) and then run this tasks in background BUT:

- oldest first,
- don't stop user for next action,
- run this tasks as quickly as possible.

How can I do it in Symfony?

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to do it?

I don't know if this "is" the best way, but the most common way to handle this type of case (*based on the fews info provided*) is:

- decouple the "operations" (*update stats , financial, usage, stock etc*) in one or more [services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html), to be able to reuse 
  it anywhere.
- create the "event" class (*at the end is a simple DTO*), in your case could be a `NewProductEvent`, where store the new product object:
- create the "listener" class `NewProductListener`, where handle which "operation" perform, in which order, etc.

> Now users must wait for I've finished all steps.

To avoid this we must be able to "dispatch" our `new_product_created` event only after the response was already served to the client and we could do this [using a service tag](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html) and more specifically the [kernel terminate event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-terminate).

**But how to store the product data to get it available on kernel.terminate?**

Let's go to implement it.

The "event" class:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use YourApp\YourBundle\Entity\Product;

class NewProductEvent extends Event
{
    const EVENT_NAME = 'new_product_created';

    protected $product;

    public function __construct(Product $newProduct)
    {
        $this->product = $newProduct;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

The "listener" class:

```
class NewProductListener
{
    protected $product;

    public function __construct()
    {
        # then you can inject all dependencies needed to perform your tasks
    }

    public function onNewProductCreated(Product $newProduct)
    {
        # here you keep in memory the product data!
        $this->product = $newProduct->getProduct();
    }

    public function performTasks()
    {
        if ($this->product) {
            # here you can put the logic to perform all needed tasks!
        }
    }
}
```

The listener "service" definition:

```
<service id="new_product_listener"
         class="YourApp\YourBundle\Event\NewProductListener">
    <!-- you can inject in the listener, as argument, each service task you need -->
    <!-- <argument type="service" id="financial_operation_service"/>-->
    <!-- <argument type="service" id="usage_operation_service"/>-->
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="new_product_created" method="onNewProductCreated"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.terminate" method="performTasks"/>
</service>
```

Now the practical example (*I don't comment the code as it is self explanatory*):

```
// presuming you are in a controller:
$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
$newProduct = //--- I don't know from where it will come.
$event      = new NewProductEvent($newProduct);
$dispatcher->dispatch(NewProductEvent::EVENT_NAME, $event);
```

When you dispatch the NewProductEvent::EVENT_NAME (`new_product_created`) you will store the product data triggering the `onNewProductCreated` method in the `$product` variable of the `NewProductListener` listeners to then be able to use it after the `kernel.terminate` event were triggered!

In this way Symfony will execute the needed tasks (*in background*) and without degrading the user experience.

Some references:

- [The EventDispatcher Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html).
- [Events and Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html).