# Listener not triggered by the event dispatcher

Tags: symfony, events, return, dispatcher

I want to execute symfony function after returning response in controller.

How can I do that ?

Here are all classes I used:

Define all events : here we have only one event defined inside this class

```
<?php
# AcmeEvents.php
namespace test\apiBundle;

final class AcmeEvents
{
    const AFTER_RETURN_RESPONSE = "acme.after_return_response";
}
```

Define the listener

```
<?php
#TestSubscriber.php
namespace test\apiBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use test\apiBundle\AcmeEvents;

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class TestSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            AcmeEvents::AFTER_RETURN_RESPONSE => 'processingFunction'
        );
    }

    public function processingFunction(Event $event)
    {
        $fs = new Filesystem();
        $fs->touch('files/myfile.json', 0700);
    }
}
```

Define the controller where the event is triggered

```
<?php
#WelcomeController.php
namespace test\apiBundle\Controller;

#use all other components
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

use test\apiBundle\AcmeEvents;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getWelcomeAction()
    {
        # all other processes
        $event = new UploadEvent();
        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->dispatch(
            'AcmeEvents::AFTER_RETURN_RESPONSE', $event
        );
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your service definiton?

Comment: acme:
        class: test\apiBundle\EventListener\TestSubscriber
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: acme.after_return_response }

Comment: Take a look at this [full example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813445/how-to-perform-tasks-avoiding-the-user-being-forced-to-wait-the-response/43814181#43814181) to see how to execute something after sending a response to the client (you have to listen to the `kernel.terminate` event).

Comment: Why you do not used a service event_dispatcher in your Action ? $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch() .. why new EventDispatcher() ??

Comment: @Mocrates Why did you delete your answer?  Looks like you have the correct solution.  Formatting could use a bit of work.

Comment: you have to use kernel.terminate event
look at this - https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-terminate-event

Comment: @Cerad because i wasn't sure about what he try to do ... create a custom event dispatcher or just used a symfony one ....

Comment: I have added this line to my service : - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: processingFunction} but I still getting the same problem

Comment: Just to clarify, in my controller, I am answering by using return response instead of response->send

Answer (score 0):

try to get a service dispatcher and not a new instance in your action :

Replace

`$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();`

by

`$this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(....)`

Comment: I have replaced it and I still getting the same problem

Comment: It have other things ... i will used dispatch(
            AcmeEvents::AFTER_RETURN_RESPONSE, $event);  ... call the constant of class ... remove the quote

Comment: I have removed the quote, the action is triggered but return section wait always the end of all processes including processingFunction inside TestSubscriber. Maybe we can give priority for each event but i think it is impossible to execute anything after return call.

Comment: try to dispatch and listen kernel.terminate even as said @ gp_sflover in a previous comment... and register your subscriber on this event

Comment: Even if we dispatch the kernel.terminate event, the return call still the latest action which is exectued in the application. I will try to use echo call instead of return. Maybe that is the only way to fix my issue